# how do i add an end finction after x amount of time in lua

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

im trying to have smooth continues mouse movement instead of using moverelative. i would like the mouse to be able to move in any direction at varying speeds and to stop after for example 150ms and then instantly start moving in another direction for another 150ms and so on. so i dont think sleep will work. this is the lua code i have so far. i got this code from someone else from an old post and am not sure how to modify it for my needs

```
do
   local frac_x, frac_y, prev_time = 0, 0

   function StartMoving()
      prev_time = GetRunningTime()
   end

   function MoveMouseForAWhile(x, y)
      Sleep(1)
      local time = GetRunningTime()
      time, prev_time = time - prev_time, time
      frac_x, frac_y = frac_x + time * x, frac_y + time * y
      x, y = math.floor(frac_x), math.floor(frac_y)
      frac_x, frac_y = frac_x - x, frac_y - y
      while x ~= 0 or y ~= 0 do
         local dx = math.min(127, math.max(-127, x))
         local dy = math.min(127, math.max(-127, y))
         x, y = x - dx, y - dy
         MoveMouseRelative(dx, dy)
      end
   end

end


EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event,arg)
   if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")then
      if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
         repeat
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
               local speed = 1.5
               StartMoving()
               repeat
                  MoveMouseForAWhile(-0.25 * speed, .35 * speed)
               until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
      end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> i would like the mouse to be able to move in any direction at varying speeds and to stop after for example 150ms and then instantly start moving in another direction for another 150ms and so on.

```
do
   local frac_x, frac_y, start_time, prev_time = 0, 0

   function StartMoving()
      prev_time = GetRunningTime()
      start_time = prev_time
   end

   function MoveMouseForAWhile(x, y)
      Sleep(1)
      local time = GetRunningTime()
      time, prev_time = time - prev_time, time
      frac_x, frac_y = frac_x + time * x, frac_y + time * y
      x, y = math.floor(frac_x), math.floor(frac_y)
      frac_x, frac_y = frac_x - x, frac_y - y
      while x ~= 0 or y ~= 0 do
         local dx = math.min(127, math.max(-127, x))
         local dy = math.min(127, math.max(-127, y))
         x, y = x - dx, y - dy
         MoveMouseRelative(dx, dy)
      end
      return prev_time - start_time
   end
end

local sequence = {
   {
      duration = 150,  -- milliseconds
      speed = 1.5,     -- pixels per 1 millisecond
      direction = 30,  -- degrees (0 = right, 90 = up, 180 = left, 270 = down)
   },
   {
      duration = 150,  
      speed = 3,     
      direction = -60, 
   },
}

function OnEvent(event,arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
      for _, seq in ipairs(sequence) do
         local angle = math.rad(seq.direction)
         local speed_x, speed_y = math.cos(angle) * seq.speed, -math.sin(angle) * seq.speed
         StartMoving()
         repeat
            local time = MoveMouseForAWhile(speed_x, speed_y)
         until time >= seq.duration
         if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then return end
      end
   end
end
```

Turn ScrollLock ON and press LMB while RMB is held down to test the script.
Release LMB to stop the script.

Comment: wow your fast and it was your code i found from before i think to lol. thank you. question. can i make it to where it only activates when both left and right mouse are pressed? also if i want more mouse movements do i just add more {sequences}? thank you very much

Comment: so i think i figured out how to add more sequences. im just wondering now how to have it activate only when left and right mouse click are pressed. thanks

Comment: oh and 1 more thing i forgot im sorry. is there a way to have the sequence end early once the mouse buttons are released? this code is pretty much exactly what i was looking for with those 2 exceptions (only activating on right then left mouse pressed, and only going through the sequence while both are are actively being held down and ending the sequence early on release of right and left mouse.) thanks

Comment: you are absolutely awesome! super fast and exactly what i was looking for! very gifted and and so nice of you to help me out with this. thank you again very much!!

Comment: hey you have done more then enough. i wanted to ask if its not to much trouble (if it is dont worry about it) i know i said to end the sequence as soon as the mouse presses where released. is there any way for it to finish out the current sequence step? so for example if i release mouse buttons 10 or 80 or any ms value within the specified duration,  it will finish out that one step, but not the rest of the sequence list. if that makes any sense? if its to much trouble no worries

Comment: Answer updated.